# Agregar función al paginado de un v-data-table

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify

He agregado una función para cambiar la paginación de mi tabla agregando desde mi javascript una función computed:

```
computed: {
    customFooterProps() {
        return {
            'items-per-page-options': this.customItemsPerPageOptions(),
            'items-per-page-text': 'Elementos por página',
            'items-per-page-all-text': 'Todos',
        }
    }
},
```

Pero, ahora quiero agregar una función que se corra cuando el usuario le da a elementos por página "TODO", solo muestre 401 elementos y se abra un v-dialog.

Probé de la siguiente manera:

**HTML**

```
<v-data-table :footer-props="customFooterProps" ref="dataTableReport" :items-per-page="400"></v-data-table>
```

**Javascript**

```
watch: {

    '$refs.dataTableReport.pagination.itemsPerPage': {
        handler(newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal === 401) {
                this.customItemsPerPageAllFunction();
            }
        },
        immediate: true
    }
},
methods: {
customItemsPerPageOptions() {
        let that = this;
        if (that.deviceSelected.length > 100) {
            return [100, 200, 400, { text: 'Todo', value: 401 }];
        } else {
            return [100, 200, 400];
        }
    },

    customItemsPerPageAllFunction() {
        console.log('Se seleccionó la opción "Todo". Aquí se abre el v-dialog');
    }
```

Pero no me funciona, ¿alguna sugerencia?

[image: Referencia]